# How to solve these inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve these inequalities?

> 1. If $a,b,c,d \gt 1$, prove that $8(abcd + 1) \gt
>     (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$.
> 2. Prove that $ \cfrac{(a+b)xy}{ay+bx} \lt \cfrac{ax+by}{a+b}$
> 3. Find the greatest value of $x^3y^5z^7$ when $2x^2+2y^2+2x^2=15$

Any hints/solution are welcome.

Comment: The first one looks like an application of Rearrangement inequality, assuming the partial order of $a,b,c,d$ from largest to smallest; second one looks like Jensen using $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, but not positive?

Comment: I hadn't given it much thought, but maybe you can prove that $2^{n-1}(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)>(x_1+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x_n+1)$ for all $n>1$ and $x_1,...,x_n>1$, by induction. This is clearly true for $n=2$. The case $n=4$ gives you 1.

Comment: I think second inequality has to have some sort of sign requirement, otherwise it is false, if both positive just apply Jensen's equality using $\varphi(\cdot) = \frac{1}{\cdot}$, $x_1 = 1/x$, $x_2 = 1/y$, $a_1 = axy$, $a_2 = bxy$

Comment: @MathChief:I didn't knew about Jensen's inequality,but I believe there might be something more easy way?!

Comment: For 2) to hold, assume that $x,y > 0$ and $x \neq y$. After some algebra, the inequality becomes $2xy < x^2 + y^2$...

Comment: No constraints is mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: The inequality is not true in general (consider $x=y$, or $a=b=x=1$ and $y=-2$).

Comment: Okay,lets try solving it your way then,any hint on the algebra?

Comment: It is easy, starting from $(axy + bxy)(a + b) < (ax + by)(ay + bx)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

1. Since $a,b,c,d>1$, then the following inequalities are true based on Rearrangement inequalities: if $x>1$ and $y>1$ then $(x-1)(y-1) > 0$, ie $xy+1 >x+y$.
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   abcd + 1 &> abc + d
   \\
   abcd + 1 &> abd + c
   \\
   abcd + 1 &> acd + b
   \\
   abcd + 1 &> bcd + a
   \\
   abcd + 1 &> ab + cd
   \\
   abcd + 1 &> ad + bc
   \\
   abcd + 1 &> ac + bd
   \\
   abcd + 1 &= abcd + 1
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   Adding them all up you get $8(abcd + 1)> (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$.
2. Assuming $a,b,x,y>0$, and $x\neq y$, using Jensen's inequality 
   $$
   \varphi(\frac{a_1 t_1+ a_2 t_2}{a_1 + a_2}) \leq \frac{a_1 \varphi(t_1)+a_2 \varphi(t_2)}{a_1 + a_2}
   $$
   where $\varphi$ is a convex function. Here take $\displaystyle \varphi(t) = \frac{1}{t}$, $\displaystyle t_1=\frac{1}{x}, t_2=\frac{1}{y}$, $a_1=axy, a_2=bxy$ , apply the inequality you have:
   $$
   \frac{(a+b)xy}{ay+bx} = \varphi\left(\frac{axy\cdot \frac{1}{x} + bxy\cdot \frac{1}{y}}{axy + bxy}\right)<\frac{axy \cdot \varphi(\frac{1}{x})+bxy\cdot \varphi(\frac{1}{x})}{axy + bxy}= \frac{ax+by}{a+b}.
   $$
3. Let $r^2 = 15/2$, then use spherical coordinates, or calculus. Or using AM-GM inequality, write 
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   x^3 y^5 z^7 &= \frac{1}{3^{5/2}\cdot 5^{3/2}\cdot (15/7)^{7/2}} \cdot \left((5x^2)^{1/5} \cdot (3y^2)^{1/3}\cdot (\frac{15}{7} z^2)^{7/15}\right)^{15/2}
   \\
   &\leq \frac{1}{3^{5/2}\cdot 5^{3/2}\cdot (15/7)^{7/2}} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{5}\cdot 5x^2 +  \frac{1}{3}\cdot 3y^2+ \frac{7}{15}\cdot \frac{15}{7} z^2\right)^{15/2}
   \\
   &=  \frac{1}{3^{5/2}\cdot 5^{3/2}\cdot (15/7)^{7/2}}\cdot (\frac{15}{2})^{\frac{15}{2}}
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   the maximum is obtained at $5x^2 = 3y^2 = \frac{15}{7} z^2$, ie, $x = \sqrt{3/2}, y= \sqrt{5/2}, z= \sqrt{7/2}$.

Comment: Third problem can be done by choosing a correct weight and applying AMGM.

Comment: @Soarer: Thank you, done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=1+x$, $b=1+y$, $c=1+z$ and $d=1+t$. Hence,
$$8(abcd + 1)-(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)=$$
$$=8(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)(1+t)+8-(2+x)(2+y)(2+z)(2+t)=$$
$$=4(xy+xz+yz+xt+yt+zt)+6(xyz+xyt+xzt+yzt)+7xyzt>0$$
Done!